# What's the difference between same wp functions get_posts(); functions in different form?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, functions, theme-development, metabox

```
get_posts('post_type=post&numberposts=-1')
```

**and the**

```
get_posts( array(
'post_type'    => 'post',
'posts_per_page' => -1
) );
```

**Are they the same?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they are, the first form is internally converted into the second. IMO you should not use the first form as it is a relic to the days wordpress DB structure was much simpler. Today I am not sure if you can even achieve all the things you can do with the second form by using the first.